# C# Visual Studio Item from combobox to texbox

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, combobox

I have a problem with MySql, combobox and textbox...
On combobox i have one column from table:

```
void ComboPlatnik()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            mysqlCon.Open();
            MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("PlatnikCombo", mysqlCon);
            mySqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            MySqlDataReader mysqlDr = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (mysqlDr.Read())
            {
                comboSolectwo.Refresh();
                comboSolectwo.Items.Add(mysqlDr.GetValue(0).ToString());
            }

        }

    }
```

and it works.
Procedure "PlatnikCombo" = SELECT nazwa FROM solectwo;
I want display in textbox first column from this table.
I created procedure:

```
PROCEDURE `SolectwoViewByNazwa`(
_SolectwoNazwa Varchar(45) ) BEGIN  SELECT idsolectwa
    FROM solectwa
    WHERE nazwa = _SolectwoNazwa; END
```

In brief:
If in combobox selected Name_1 then in textbox display ID_1.

This:

```
private void txtIDSolectwo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            mysqlCon.Open();
            MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("SolectwoViewByNazwa", mysqlCon);
            mySqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            MySqlDataReader mysqlDr = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (mysqlDr.Read())
            {
                txtIDSolectwo.Text = (mysqlDr.GetValue(0).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Dosn't works...
Please... Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution:

```
private void comboSolectwo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            mysqlCon.Open();
            MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM solectwa WHERE nazwa='"+comboSolectwo.Text+"';", mysqlCon);
            MySqlDataReader mysqlDr = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (mysqlDr.Read())
            {
                string sID = mysqlDr.GetInt32("idsolectwa").ToString();
                txtIDSolectwo.Text = sID;
            }

        }


    }
```

Its works.